# HTML : from select list need to add value to mysql

Tags: mysql, html

I have an html drop down with some values like :

This one is inside form :

```
<b>Priority</b><select><name = "priority" id="priority"><option>Low</option><option>Medium </option><option>High</option></select>
```

Now when I click submit, What the value I select should be inserted to db. For that iadded like :

```
$priority = $_POST['priority'];
$sql3= "INSERT INTO work (priority) VALUES ('$priority')";
```

But it throw error : unknown identifier.

So how can I get the value from the select and insert into db. Pleasehelp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
<select><name = "priority" id="priority">
```

to:

```
<select name="priority" id="priority">
```